# PDFBOX - when signing PDF, SignatureInterface's sign is not called

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, sign

I'm trying to sign PDF using PDFBOX library (mostly following `CreateSignature` and other classes from the `example` package in GitHub).

Having taken the `SignatureInterface` approach, I'm providing the one to the `addSignature`, yet the `sign` method **is not being called**.

Relevant code snippet:

```java
private void signPDF(PDDocument document) throws Exception {
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    signature.setName("iSure");
    signature.setLocation("IL");
    signature.setReason("Security");
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));

    // this is the only 'foreign' call here, it looks exactly as in example
    setMDPPermission(document, signature, 1);

    document.addSignature(signature, new Signer());
}
```

Immediately after calling `signPDF`, the document is being saved into an `OutputStream`.

PS: in the MDP permissions, I needed to remove "DigestMethod" entry, it fails PDF/A metadata validation - correct?

Comment: The signature is created during incremental saving. Please follow the `Create*Signature*` examples up to and including that saving step.

Comment: Yep, I've discovered it myself debugging the `COSWriter` and posted below the working code (with some design concerns :) ), thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, tracing the `COSWriter` flow, I've finally found that when the save is not **incremental**, writing signature methods are not being called at all. This part is clearly stated in the examples, yet I've thought that it is relevant only for those specific scenarios or for a continuation of working with `PDDocument`, while my case is when signing is actually termination operation in the flow. Bottom line - my bad :(

So I've changed the method above as following:

```java
// since forced to saveIncremental, need to finilized the input document and return a new one
private PDDocument signPDF(PDDocument document) throws Exception {
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    ... this part stays exactly as it was
    document.addSignature(signature, new Signer());

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        document.saveIncremental(baos);
        return PDDocument.load(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to pass the target `OutputStream` to the `signPDF` method and perform the actual flow termination here: saving the document and closing it afterwards.

Yet another one would be to call `saveIncremental` in the main flow (`signPDF` caller).

All those variation fill to me like rolling foreign concerns between the methods... If anyone has some better way to lay it out - I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: I propose you don't return a `PDDocument` but instead the byte array. If the caller saves the `PDDocument` inappropriately, he will have a broken signature.